# missing ) after argument list when calling function in javascript

Tags: javascript

> Hi. I want to start off by saying that I know, probably the solution is here somewhere but I will ask because I have tested for 3 - 4 hours some different methods.

My code is working fine until I click my buttons.
Here is my code:

```
function traningData(data) {
var traning = data.val();
var keys = Object.keys(traning);
var data = [];
var text = "";

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys [i];
    var name = traning [k].name;
    var desc = traning [k].description;
    var uid = traning [k].uid;
    var type = traning [k].type;

    text += '<button onClick="readItemData('+name+')">'+name+'</button>';
```

The problem is in my onClick code for the button

> onClick="readItemData('+name+')"

When I press the button to run my readItemData() I get the following error in the console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

**How is it supposed to look inside the onClick when I try to pass it all
as a string in to my text string?**

## **UPDATE**

Here is how the button looks when i inspect the element:

```
   "<button onclick="readItemData(Bodyweight row)">Bodyweight row</button>"
```

> ## **SOLUTION**
>
> I could not sleep until i fixed this problem, so here is my solution,
>
> "text += 'onclick="readItemData('+"'"+name+"'"+')">'+name+'';"

Comment: Thanks for that. Sure there are other answers that don't work, so please answer this question.

Comment: You certainly shouldn't have spaces between `keys` and `[i]` and between `traning` and `[k]`. Also, `onClick` should be lowercase.

Comment: Check that case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onclick

Comment: What is `data.val();` ? form is similar to jQuery object but what does a `console.log( data.val());` show you?

Comment: On the page, right click that button and then paste that markup in here on your question.

Comment: So I have change the spacing and have lower-case onclick, the data.val(); is for Firebase.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I have update with how the button looks in inspection